# R subsetting a data frame based on a factor variable formatted like a range (xx-xx)

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, r-factor

I am facing this problem for many hours now, but I know I am missing something obvious.

Here is my problem:

I have a data-frame in .xlsx file that can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uc2cnbpcl51tb7v/Evolution_Population_2004_2020.xlsx).

I loaded this data-frame into R using RStudio on MAc and called it demoData.
There are 5 variables (AgeRange, Women, Men, Total, and Year).

I am not able to subset this data frame with a condition on the AgeRange. The format of this variable is as follow: xx-xx (00-04 meaning people between 00 and 04 years old). The message I have when I try to do that is that there is no row filling this condition. 
The class of the variable "AgeRange" is factor.

Here is my code:

```
demoData[demoData$AgeRange=="00-04",]
```

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** from Arun. Here's input from `head(demoData)`:

```
     Age Feminin Masculin. Ensemble Annee
1 00-04     720       745     1465  2004 
2 05-09     745       767     1512  2004 
3 10-14     813       830     1643  2004 
4 15-19     824       820     1644  2004 
5 20-24     839       823     1662  2004 
6 25-29     752       699     1450  2004 

# str(demoData)
'data.frame':   272 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Age      : Factor w/ 16 levels "00-04 ","05-09 ",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Feminin  : Factor w/ 216 levels "138 ","139 ",..: 112 124 164 165 174 130 106 86 78 66 ...
 $ Masculin.: Factor w/ 201 levels "120 ","122 ",..: 132 141 174 169 170 124 111 89 90 75 ...
 $ Ensemble : Factor w/ 242 levels "1041 ","1044 ",..: 53 66 115 116 119 50 38 14 9 238 ...
 $ Annee    : Factor w/ 17 levels "2004 ","2005",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Please provide a subset of your data with `dput(head(demoData))`. It can be painful to load `xlsx` files into R.

Comment: Your variable is called `Age`, not `AgeRange` ?

Comment: You've a space after "00-04 ". That's the problem. Try `demoData[demoData$Age == "00-04 "]`

Comment: And can you show `summary( demoData )`?

Comment: @Arun How could you tell there was a space from the posted code? They all look like spaces to me!

Comment: @SimonO101, I'm the one editing the post. I already loaded the data and checked it. At least that's what I think is happening. I used `read.xlsx` from `xlsx` package.

Comment: unfortunately, adding space doesn't work either.

Comment: @Arun oh right - the link to the data was posted. Of course! I thought you had some kind of magic way of determining delimiting spaces from spaces!!!

Comment: The last character doesn't seem to be space... using `gsub` doesn't remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I read in your xlsx file with the xlsx package:

```
df<-read.xlsx("C:/Users/swatson1/Downloads/Evolution_Population_2004_2020.xlsx",1)
```

and it looked like this:

```
> df
        Age Feminin MasculinÂ. Ensemble  Annee
1   00-04Â    720Â       745Â    1465Â  2004Â 
2   05-09Â    745Â       767Â    1512Â  2004Â
```

You could replace each column, getting rid of the extra character with something like:

```
df$Age<-substr(df$Age,1,5)
```

Alternatively, use `gsub` as this will work on any column regardless of the length of the entry:

```
df$Age<-gsub("Â\\s","",df$Age)
```

Then your code would work:

```
df[df$Age=="00-04",]
```

Comment: (+1) It's better to remove the last character rather than say 1:5, as there are also Age values like: `75 &+`.

Comment: Agreed, I think `gsub` would be more useful in this case - will make edit.

Comment: I finally used the following code to solve the problem:
`x<-gsub("\xC2\xA0","",x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#coppied from the Excel file 
str1 <- "00-04 "
utf8ToInt(str1)
#[1]  48  48  45  48  52 160
```

There seems to be a no-break space at the end of the string. Sanitize your file.

You should be able to remove the no-break spaces using

```
df$Age <- gsub(intToUtf8(160),"",df$Age)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answers. However I am still not able to remove the no-break spaces in the data frame. Suppose I would like to remove only the no-break spaces (I dont see the Â in my file), what I am supposed to do ?
I tried to deal with that in Excel using the functions Substitute but I am no able to use the data as "value" vs. formulas.. Thank you gain for your help. This no-break spaces make me crazy :)

Comment: See the edit.  However, I cannot test the solution on your data, because I won't read Excel files directly into R. I always read data from CSV files.